# MQTT topic transform in Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, fiware

I'm working on integrating a Shelly sensor(https://shelly.cloud/) into an existed IoT system FIWARE(https://www.fiware.org/). The sensor can publish the monitoring data via MQTT with JSON payload.

Shelly sensor published the data at topic **{SHELLY_ID}/events/rpc**, but the FIWARE can only subscribe on topic **/json/{{api-key}}/{{device-id}}/attrs**. The topic of publication and subscription are different now. In our application, we use **Mosquitto** as an MQTT broker, is it possible to do the topic transform in Mosquitto broker?

I think Mosquitto has full knowledge of topics and can do the topic mapping and transformation easily. Does anyone have an idea or information for this? I think it's much easier than to re-build and customize the FIWARE system.

Answer (score 1):

Mosquitto does not support generic topic remapping.

The only place it has any support is

1. Adding a prefix when mapping topics over a bridge
2. Adding a prefix as a mount point for a listener

The simplest way to solve this problem is to write a client to do the remapping

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It's a good idea that writes a client to subscribe topic1, then re-format the payload and re-publish on topic2. It's feasible, thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the exact same issue(with FIWARE) with a polar H10 sensor, i found a very "lets call it a dirty" work around.
I created an intermediate python program which listens to the specific topics and republishes it to the new topic